# How frequently should I modify my title tags and meta description tags on my web pages?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, meta-description

I am new in this digital marketing industry and learning about SEO best practices, but I am confused about the meta tags that how frequently should I change meta tags of website's pages?

Changing meta tags manually can be possible for small websites like 30-50 pages website, but what about e-commerce websites?

Is there any Auto Tagging tool? which can automatically generate meta tags for my website's pages and automatically change them after a particular time interval.

Comment: Why do you want to change them? Do you want to include sale offers or something else? You have tagged the meta-description and meta-refresh. Can you explain the meta-refresh tag?

Comment: There are lot's of meta tags, specify which one you said in your question?. If it is Keywords meta tags then don't waste your time on it, google don't use it, [checkout the video and read article](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812) And please use tags on your question properly. By mentioning too many tags wont give you better or instant answer. I also recommended you to to [reference google guidelines first](https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/6001981?hl=en&ref_topic=3309300), because it seems you're following wrong way to learn seo.

Comment: I mean Meta Title and Meta Description. I know very well that Meta keywords are not important now. Annd Meta Refresh is a meta tag which is use to redirect page automatically and you set the time during after that page redirect to the new web page where you would like to redirect the page. For an example -- 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/">
(This will redirect the user to http://example.com after 5 second)

Comment: Can you please tell me about Auto Tagging tool which is used for e-commerce websites?

Comment: What is reason behind changing tons of webpages title and meta description? Do you think it make the page fresh and you'll get better ranking?

Comment: Yeah I think so if we change our website's meta titles and descriptions frequently like once in a period of 2 or 3 months then we may get extra attention from the search engine's bots and we can easily achieve top rank for our targeted keywords. Sorry but I am new and I don't have any idea about it that's why i would like clear my confusion with you all industry experts or professionals.

Comment: First, there is not auto-tagging tool so please stop looking. Auto tagging is just not realistically possible and therefore no such thing. Second, you do not want to change title and description tags unless they are bad and you want to improve them. Otherwise, traditionally, these are set then left alone. Any change to these tags should be avoided unless there is a obvious performance issue. Changing these tags does not garner more attention. It could potentially put you on the spam list.

Comment: @closetnoc Thank you. That's ok that we should not change meta tag until or unless it is bad or not appropriate for the particular landing page.

Comment: @closetnoc Still I have one more query that is how to manage meta tags for eCommerce website where hundreds of pages are published everyday and most of them are published by the seller by themselves. I think that sellers never create meta tags for the product pages then who creates tags for those page and How to manage meta data creation for so many web pages everyday.

Comment: I would require one. If not, then I would use manufacturer, model, product such as Sony, XBR Super-Platinum, Television. (made up the model) This should be relatively simple to do depending upon how users are required to enter products.

Answer (score 4):

When you encounter one of the following:

- Your content changes rendering the current title incorrect/incomplete
- You've learned how to phraze it better (e.g. experience, or A/B tests)
- SEO rules regarding best practice for meta tags change

---

Based on your question, I'm guessing you're a beginner, so to stick with beginner advice:

Just make sure every page has a unique title (meta title) and an unique meta description. Don't worry about the rest. Don't stuff it with keywords, create content for visitors, not bots. A good basis to start with it:

```
[the title of the page] - [sitename/companyname]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Martijn. What is A/B testing and how to implement it?

Comment: Google is your friend ;)

Comment: @Martijn Google is my friend? With friends like that who needs... ;-) I could not resist. Cheers!!

Answer (score -4):

You can Update frequently. Whenever Google bot crawl it checks meta keywords, meta title, and meta description

Comment: I don't think this answer is accurate.  Google doesn't use meta keywords at all.  The frequency with which Googlebot re-checks a page depends on many factors including reputation.  Some popular pages will get recrawled daily, but must pages get recrawled only every couple weeks.